# Is there any way to get Google Desktop Search to index Microsoft OneNote data?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, google-desktop-search

I have recently started using Microsoft OneNote, and I like many things about it.

However, Google Desktop Search does not seem to be aware of stuff stored there.

Is there any way to get [Google Desktop Search](http://desktop.google.com/) to index [Microsoft OneNote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/default.aspx) data?

I've tried the obvious:

1 - [Searched for a plugin here](http://desktop.google.com/plugins)

2 - [Saw others complaining about the issue here](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.onenote&tid=b9482b7c-61f4-4607-8425-e21a5123b87c&cat=en_US_d02fc761-3f6b-402c-82f6-ba1a8875c1a7&lang=en&cr=&sloc=en-us&m=1&p=1)

3 - [Asked Google about it](http://www.google.com/search?q=google+desktop+search+microsoft+onenote)

Comment: Good question, precise, and ruling out the obvious, really good. It opens the way for interesting answers.

Comment: If you looked that well I hope the answer isn't: NO

Comment: Joseph, do you have "Enhanced Content Indexing" turned on in the options page in Google Desktop Search? That may do the trick! I don't use OneNote, so I can't confirm for you though.

Comment: @Kyle; good question, yes I do have that enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [IFilterShop](http://desktop.google.com/plugins/i/ifiltershop.html?hl=en) plugin which let's GDS work with installed Microsoft iFilters (which are used by Windows Indexing Service).

Download and install the [MS Office 2007 filter pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=60C92A37-719C-4077-B5C6-CAC34F4227CC&displaylang=en) which includes OneNote filters and then install IFilterShop.

N.B. I haven't tried this myself... so good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Do you HAVE to use Google desktop search?

1. It's a memory hog
2. Microsoft inbuilt search sucked prior to the release of Windows Search 4.0 but now it's awesome.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/default.mspx

Comment: I prefer GDS over Windows Search (even 4.0, which I've tried), because it  uses less memory than Windows Search, and also less processor time.  It is also more flexible about searching network locations, and plugins allow me to search inside source code files, which Windows Search won't do.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used GDS so I'm just throwing out some random ideas here.

What does GDS index? Documents? Static Web page (.html files) on your disk?

Those questions are leading... If you can expose the OneNote data as one of the formats that GDS indexes then you will probably be able to get GDS to index it. For example, you could have a cron job that checks your One Note database every X minutes and have it run something (like a powershell script) that writes/exports the One Note data as HTML files to a folder on your hard disk that GDS could then index.

This solution idea sucks on many levels (duplication of data, cron jobs, data only updated every X minutes etc.) but it might work.

Good luck.